# Elastic counting number of changes at each entry?

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene

Is there anyway to count how many times a value has changed in a specific time period.

For example, I have the following info stored in my index.

```
Index Name Result TimeStamp
idx16   A    7     March 7th 2018, 16:17:35.000
idx16   A    7     March 7th 2018, 16:17:36.000
idx16   A    8     March 7th 2018, 16:17:37.000
idx16   A    7     March 7th 2018, 16:17:38.000
idx16   B    1     March 7th 2018, 16:17:35.000
idx16   B    2     March 7th 2018, 16:17:36.000
idx16   B    3     March 7th 2018, 16:17:37.000
idx16   B    7     March 7th 2018, 16:17:38.000
idx16   C    1     March 7th 2018, 16:17:35.000
idx16   C    1     March 7th 2018, 16:17:36.000
idx16   C    1     March 7th 2018, 16:17:37.000
idx16   C    1     March 7th 2018, 16:17:38.000
```

The desired result would A changed 2, B changed 3 and C changed 0 times ?

Comment: is it list of documents?

Comment: yeah it is a list of documents

Comment: I mean, in your example you have 12 different documents, and you want to get those statistics about changing, right?

Comment: Yes, so in this case the B document changed 3 times it went from result 1 to 2 then to 2 to 3 and then 3 to 7 :)